# How to link a style sheet?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to link my CSS sheet with the HTML code that I have created in VScode. Below are the screenshots.
[HTML snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xOi1.png)

[CSS sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lnm06.png)

Comment: You should insert the code in proper markup instead of pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's a slight error in your pathing.

This line here:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css" />`

Should be changed to this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />`

Notice the removed `/` from the .css file path.

When the file your referencing is in the same directory as the file your referencing *from*, no slashes are needed in the path!